# Volume control with MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using MPMusicPlayerController to change system volume using my slider:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     MPMusicPlayerController musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChanged:) name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Then I have implemented following methods to change the sound:

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender{
    [musicPlayer setVolume:  sender.value];
}
- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float volume =[[[notification userInfo]   objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]floatValue];
    [self.volumSeekbar setValue:musicPlayer.volume];
}
```

When I change volume with my seeker it shown the system volume controller, is there any way to prevent showing that?

edit: MPVolume default image with good quality but a little big!
[image]

Comment: Check out MPVolumeView, this is the system supplied way to change your device's volume. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/

Comment: @amergin Thanks, I am using MPVolume but I can't set a good image to it's thumb image. Do you know what should be the size to get a good view for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the images I use - I've only included the 1x sizes - thumb is 54 x 30

```
[self.mpVolumeView setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"master_volume_bar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.mpVolumeView setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_volume_bar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.mpVolumeView setVolumeThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_thumb"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: master_volume_bar]

[image: grey_volume_bar]

[image: volume_thumb]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want an image like iOS default volume image (circular), I will attach an image to my question so you can see the quality of my output

Comment: If you want to use the default value then just leave it as is. If you want a custom image then use a graphics editor to create three copies, the original as well as a 2x and 3x copy.

Comment: Quality is gonna be ok if I use the default image but it is too big!

Comment: So use a graphics app to create a small white disc then save it as volume_thumb.png (20x20px), volume_thumb@2x.png (40x40px) and volume_thumb@3x.png (60x60px) - or whatever size you'd like.

Comment: I have tried all these sizes but when I set image it's gonna be something like the one I attached, there are blur effects on it's outlines

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the uploaded image. It looks like you just used my 1x image. On a retina screen it will scale it up to 2x which is why you're seeing blurring on the edges. If you display it on an iPhone 6+ screen it will look for a 3x image and not finding it will scale the 1x image up three times giving an even blurrier image. You need three copies of every image. The original size, one double the size, and a third one three times the size (see my comment two above).

Comment: This screen shot is for iPhone5s. What should I set to have is correct on iPhone 5s?

Comment: Just rename the image to volume_thumb@2x.png

Comment: Renaming the image will change it's quality?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89063/discussion-between-amergin-and-niloufar).

Comment: Same names. 4s is also a retina device so it will pick up and use the @2x version of the image